# Creating tasks for multiple users

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks, task-list

I am new to sharepoint, did not even know it existed last month. My boss would like me to create a sharepoint list with multiple tasks/jobs, with a field to assign those tasks to certain people. Then she would like jobs to be completed sequentially. For example: Bill gets an email to get a bucket, when he clicks complete, Josh gets an email to fill it with water, etc. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom list with status fields and people pickers for each "task". Then use SharePoint designer to handle the validation logic an email sending for your workflow. I also create a choice field to act as a switch to change from no to yes when the email is sent. After each email I have the workflow set the email sent status to yes. This also helps the users know how far along the process is and what emails were sent.

Basics:

Columns:

- Task A Stats (Choice: Incomplete, Complete)
- Person A (people picker for email)
- Email A Sent (Choice: Yes, No)

(repeat fields for as many times as you need)

Workflow:

- IF Person A is not empty
- AND task A status is Incomplete
- AND Email A Sent is NO

  - Then send Task A Email (to person A)
  - AND set Email A Sent to Yes.

(repeat logic as needed)

This is just one way to do it as you can customize the list and workflow to meet any other requirements that I may have missed.

Answer (score 1):

**This** is called a workflow, you can create a workflows with more than one way, as in your case i'd suggest using the **Approval – SharePoint 2010** workflow which already included in SharePoint and you can apply it in your list or library by following the below instructions.

Follow these steps:

1. Open the list or library for which you want to add the workflow.
2. On the ribbon, click the `List or Library tab`.
   Note: The name of the tab can vary with the type of list or library. For example, in a calendar list the tab is named Calendar.
3. In the Settings group, click `Workflow Settings`.
4. On the `Workflow Settings` page, under Show workflow associations of this type, specify if you want the workflow to run on the document, list, or a folder and then click `Add a workflow`.
5. Complete the first page of the association form.
   [image]

> **1. Content type**
>
> Keep the default selection as All, or select a specific content type.
>
> **2. Template**
>
> Select the Approval – SharePoint 2010 template.
>       Note: If the Approval – SharePoint 2010 template doesn’t appear in the list, check this link for [how to enable it](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/content-approval/enabling-using-sharepoint-approval-workflow-exercise.cfm).
>
> **3. Name**
>
> Type a name for this workflow. The name will identify this workflow to users of this list or library.
>
> **4. Task List**
>
> Select a task list to use with this workflow. You can select an existing task list or click New task list to have a new list created.
>
> **5. History List**
>
> Select a history list to use with this workflow. You can select an existing history list or click Workflow History (new) to have a new
>   list created.
>
> **6. Start Options**
>
> Specify the way or ways in which this workflow can be started.

6. When all of the settings in this form are the way you want them,
    click `Next`.
 7. Complete the second page of the association form.

> Note: SharePoint products presents you with the first several options
>   in this second page of the association form — numbers one through
>   seven in the following illustration, from Approvers through CC — each
>   time that you start the workflow manually, so that you can make
>   changes to those options for just that one instance.

[image]

> **1.     Assign to**
>
> Enter names or addressed for the people you want the workflow to
>   assign tasks to.
>
> - If the tasks will be assigned one at a time (in serial)    Enter the    names or addresses in the order in which the tasks should be
>     assigned.
> - If all of the tasks will be assigned at the same time (in parallel)      The order of the names or addresses doesn’t matter.
>
> **2.Order**
>
> Specify whether the tasks should be assigned one at a time (in serial)
>   or all at once (in parallel).
>
> **3.Add a new stage**
>
> Add any stages that you want beyond the first one that you’ve just
>   configured.
>
> - To delete an entire stage, click in the Assign To field for that    stage, and then press CTRL+DELETE.
>
> **4.Expand groups**
>
> - To have one task assigned to each member of each group that you enter    in the Assign to field, select this check box. (Each member
>     of the    group will receive a task notification, and each member will
>     have his    or her own task to complete.)
> - To have only one task assigned to each entire group that you enter in    the Assign to field, clear this check box. (Each member of the
>     group    will receive a task notification, but any one member can
>     claim and    complete the single task on behalf of the whole group.
>
> **5.Request**
>
> Any text that you include here will be included in each task
>   notification that the workflow sends. Don’t forget to include any
>   additional instructions or resources that participants might need,
>   including:
>
> - Contact information.
> - If appropriate, a note about single tasks assigned to entire groups    or distribution lists.
>
> **6.Due dates and task duration**
>
> Specify a final due date for the entire workflow, and/or specify the
>   number of days, weeks, or months allowed for the completion of each
>   task from the time when it’s assigned.
>
> - If this workflow will ever start automatically, it’s usually a good      idea to leave the Due Date for All Tasks field empty and to
>     use the    two duration fields to control the due date. You can always
>     supply a    precise due date in the initiation form if and when you
>     start the    workflow manually.
>
> **7.CC**
>
> Enter the names or email addresses anyone of who should be notified
>   each time the workflow starts or ends.
>
> - Entering a name here doesn’t    result in the assignment of a workflow task.
> - When the workflow is   started manually, the person who starts it receives the start and stop   notifications without needing to be
>     specified in this field.
> - When the workflow is started automatically, the person who originally    added   it receives the start and stop notifications
>     without needing to be   specified in this field.
>
> **8.Ending the workflow**
>
> Select neither, either, or both of these options.
>
> **9.Enable content approval**
>
> Select this check box if you will be using this workflow to manage
>   content approval.

When you have all of the settings in this page the way you want them, click **Save** to create the workflow.